# cassandra vs. bigchainDB(and all other distibuted databases)

Tags: cassandra, blockchain, distributed, bigchaindb

I want to use blockchain features to provide security for my database.
But the hardest part of this transportation is finding a suitable destination.
I did lots of research but I couldn't find an answer.
My main problem is the difference between Cassandra and BigchianDB and the parameters that I should consider for choosing a suitable decentralized database?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe mentioning what you found in your research and what did you expect might help those who'd try to answer your quesiton.  See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)